# What is the input size of Alex net

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

In the paper ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks, the size of input image is 224x224. The following figure shows the input size.
[image]

From caffe, deploy.prototxt file from the directory of the bvlc_alexnet says that the input size is 227x227.
[image]

Why is the input size different?

Comment: I don't have reputation to comment so I am asking a small follow-up. does the 10 represent batch size and 3 represent the RGB channels?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess it has been a mistake. Take a look at [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/MmYe2/classic-networks).

> The other author's were Ilya Sutskever and Geoffrey Hinton. So, AlexNet input starts with 227 by 227 by 3 images. And if you read the paper, the paper refers to 224 by 224 by 3 images. But if you look at the numbers, I think that the numbers make sense only of actually 227 by 227.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on [@Media's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29247/32433), what is meant by *"I think that the numbers make sense only if they're actually 227 by 227"* is the following:

In the attached snapshot, the size of the 1st convolution layer is $55x55$. Now suppose the dimensions of the input images are $224x224$, then by applying the $11x11$ kernels with $stride=4$ as described in the paper, would result in:

$outsize=\frac{(insize+2*padding-kernel)}{stride}+1$

$outsize=\frac{(224+2*0-11)}{4}+1=54.25$

Whereas if the dimensions were $227x227$, then that would result in:

$outsize=\frac{(227+2*0-11)}{4}+1=55$

which conforms with the size of the 1st convolution layer described in the paper.

---

** I got the formula for calculating the output size from [this YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/wnK3uWv_WkU?t=234).*